# AVCaptureSession exact time stamp when a frame is grabbed

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, avcapturesession

I am inside of a AVCaptureSession and I need to know the number of the frame being captured.

When the capture starts, I will reset a frame number counter to zero. So, the timestamp of the first frame will be zero. Subsequent frames will have capture timestamps like this, for example:

```
0
0.033
0.066
0.099
etc
```

but these are not exact numbers, because frames can be dropped and slight differences may happen. I need to know the exact time when a frame was captured.

I have this method that is called every time a frame is grabbed...

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
```

inside this method I can obtain the CMTime of a frame and print it to the console using:

```
CMTime timestamp = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp( sampleBuffer );
NSLog(@"%lld", timestamp.value);
```

but this will give me wild numbers like

```
156317265588132
156317307247388
156317348909678
156317390573453
156317432230603
```

the difference between one number and the next is about 41,659,256 that does not seem to represent a time in seconds with decimal places when the frame is grabbed.

if I divide this numbers by the timescale, using

```
NSLog(@"%lld", timestamp.value/timestamp.timescale);
```

the numbers will be the same for 25 frames and will only change when a full second is reached.

How do I obtain the exact time stamp in seconds with decimal places when a frame is grabbed?  thanks.

Comment: i tried to get this , value , but it gave me a wrong value not current timestamp

Comment: CMTimeGetSeconds(timestamp)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If I divide this numbers by the timescale, the numbers will be the same for 25 frames and will only change when a full second is reached.

Because integer division truncates. How about

```
NSLog(@"%f", (float)timestamp.value / timestamp.timescale);
```

Comment: i tried to get this , value , but it gave me a wrong value not current timestamp